# VS code debugger variables not showing up

Tags: jestjs, visual-studio-code

I am trying to debug a test in vscode.
jest is runner.
Here is my launch configuration.

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
      {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Jest All",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/jest/bin/jest",
        "args": ["--runInBand"],
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
        "sourceMaps": true      }
    ]
  }
```

Using this when i launch the debugger it stops at breakpoint but none of the variables show up in local variable pane.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cm4zq.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (if u are on windows):

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
      {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Jest All",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/jest",
        "args": ["--runInBand"],
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
        "disableOptimisticBPs": true,
        "windows": {
          "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/jest/bin/jest",
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Jest Current File",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/jest",
        "args": [
          "${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
          "--config",
          "jest.config.js"
        ],
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
        "disableOptimisticBPs": true,
        "windows": {
          "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/jest/bin/jest",
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: adding that did it.Thanks.May i ask is it  "windows": { that does the trick?

Comment: gonna be honest, I don't pay too too much attention to those config files, I just keep trying stuff till they work lol